# Как правильно писать XPath c namespace?

Tags: xpath

Работаю с библиотекой libxml2. Нужно получить узел XML "ds:SignedInfo" со всеми детьми.

Вот XML документ:

```
<pirs:ImportRequest xmlns:pirs="http://roskazna.ru/xsd/PGU_ImportRequest">
<PostBlock>
    <ID>18526a7d-954d-11e2-91a6-001d600da737</ID>
    <TimeStamp>2013-04-11T17:28:14Z</TimeStamp>
    <SenderIdentifier>00004</SenderIdentifier>
</PostBlock>
<Charge SupplierBillID="M0000413Р‘РЈ0000000019">
    <BillDate>2013-03-25</BillDate>
    <SupplierOrgInfo>
        <Name>1C-Test</Name>
        <INN>7702778142</INN>
        <KPP>771401001</KPP>
        <OGRN>1077328004676</OGRN>
        <Account>
            <Account>40601810800003010041</Account>
        </Account>
    </SupplierOrgInfo>
    <TotalAmount>750000</TotalAmount>
    <AdditionalData>
        <Name>SRV_CODE</Name>
        <Value>AAAAA000040000000001</Value>
    </AdditionalData>
    <ChangeStatus>1</ChangeStatus>
    <KBK>00000000000000000000</KBK>
    <OKATO>11111111111</OKATO>
    <BudgetIndex>
        <Status>0</Status>
        <PaymentType>0</PaymentType>
        <Purpose>0</Purpose>
        <TaxPeriod>0</TaxPeriod>
        <TaxDocNumber>0</TaxDocNumber>
        <TaxDocDate>0</TaxDocDate>
    </BudgetIndex>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gostr34102001-gostr3411"></ds:SignatureMethod><ds:Reference URI="#body"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gostr3411"></ds:DigestMethod><ds:DigestValue>ooJDUQfsxNi5L8nqvXDpakrOLEBxYWcjKulWq+pmZ4I=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>3u4iVm4s/eT+a8Y+nvlNCcLed0+YlYb39uYaAHZnZ+7fnjrC2Jk1vOyOFqN4ShMHrjHll22hR1l9QxRs5vWRiA==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><SerurityTokenReference><Reference URI="#CernId" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"></Reference></SerurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature>
</Charge>
```

</pirs:ImportRequest>

Код простой:

```
std::string XMLDoc::xPath(const std::string& xPathExpr)
{    std::string     retNode;

/* Create xpath evaluation context */
xmlXPathContextPtr  xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(m_pXMLDoc);
if (xpathCtx == NULL)
    return retNode;

/* Evaluate xpath expression */
xmlXPathObjectPtr   xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(BAD_CAST xPathExpr.c_str(), xpathCtx);
if (xpathObj == NULL)
    return retNode;

/* Cleanup */
xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);

// Пробовал использовать namespace
//xmlChar*    ns[] = {BAD_CAST "ds", NULL};
xmlChar*    c14nTag = NULL;
if (xmlC14NDocDumpMemory(m_pXMLDoc, (xpathObj->nodesetval ? xpathObj->nodesetval: NULL), 1, NULL /*ns*/, (int)false, &c14nTag) > 0)
{
    retNode = (char*)c14nTag;
    xmlFree(c14nTag);
}

if (xpathObj)
    xmlXPathFreeObject(xpathObj);

return retNode;
```

}

Если я выдаю на вход этой функции XPath выражение вида "`//Charge/descendant-or-self::node()`", то отлично все работает. Выдает весь узел, но если это применить к узлам с namespace-ом, то получается пустая выборка узлов "`//SignedInfo/descendant-or-self::node()`". Я пробовал разные комбинации XPath, но не удается получить узел со всеми детьми.

**Вопрос: "Как правильно написать XPath-выражение, чтобы получить узел "ds:SignedInfo", со всеми детьми?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нужно было добавить контексту XPath namespace-ы:

   ```
   xmlXPathRegisterNs(xpathCtx, BAD_CAST "ds", BAD_CAST "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
   ```
2. В канонизированном виде в тэги не попадали объявления пространств имен. Вот выражение, которое работает `"(//. | //@* | //namespace::*)[ancestor-or-self::ds:SignedInfo]"`

Так что, С-шный код с добавлением "1)" - успешно ищет узлы с namespace-ами.